# Russian language not support android

Tags: android, localization

I have Russian language data and want to display it, but strange symbols display on the screen.

Below is my code :

```
public ArrayList<String> ReadFromfile(String fileName, Context context, boolean isArabic) {
    ArrayList<String> temparray = new ArrayList<String>();
    AssetManager assestManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream input;
    BufferedReader bufferReader;
    try {
        input = assestManager.open(fileName);
        if (isArabic)
            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
        else
       //bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "windows-1252"));
        bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "\u041a\u043e\u0440\u0430\u043b\u044c"));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            temparray.add(line);
        }
        bufferReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
    return temparray;

}
```

How Russain Language data can be displayed ???

Comment: Where is your data from? Just be sure the original source is encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: Orignal data is saved in UTF-8 formate. assests folder

Comment: @Yoann Hercouet..you right.now it is fixed